# php export sqlite table to csv

Tags: php, sqlite, csv

I'm trying to export a table to a CSV file using php and it's working with the following code:

```
while($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
        print '"' . stripslashes(implode('","',$row)) . "\"\n";
    }
```

However, it creates duplicates of each field when I view the CSV file. I don't know how to limit them down to one per field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`fetchArray`](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php) returns both associative and numeric indices by default. To return only numeric indices use:

```
while($row = $results->fetchArray( SQLITE3_NUM )) {
```

Or to return an associative array use:

```
while($row = $results->fetchArray( SQLITE3_ASSOC )) {
```

Comment: Thanks Sébastien that worked perfectly! I knew I was missing something simple like that.

Answer (score 1):

This is because [`SQLite3Result::fetchArray`](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php) by default fetches both a numeric and a named index for each column in the result. So `$row` might look like this:

```
array(
    0 => 'Fred',
    'firstname' => 'Fred',
    1 => 'Jones',
    'lastname' => 'Jones',
    2 => 'fredjones@example.com',
    'email' => 'fredjones@example.com'
)
```

The way around this is to specify other behaviour in the `fetchArray` call by passing a constant:

```
while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
```

This means that only the names of the columns will be fetched. Equally, you could do `SQLITE3_NUM`: in your case it would make no difference.

Note also that a nicer way to output CSV data is with the [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) method, which handles enclosure and escaping as necessary. It requires a file handle: if you just want to echo the data, you can use the `STDOUT` constant:

```
fputcsv(STDOUT, $row);
```

[Running example](http://ideone.com/Eh47lX)